# Is it safe to remove all CLSID/GUID folders appearing on my Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, home-folder, guid

I recently uninstalled a lot of programs and suddenly two weird folders appeared on my desktop. Both have no name, right click options are just: Cut, Create Shortcut and Delete.

There's a file extension or type in file explorer:
[image: weird folders]

I googled about them but nothing found.
Is it safe to delete them?

EDIT 1: These doesn't show up in cmd: [image: cmd cant see them]
EDIT 2: When clicking delete, this shows up: [image: control panel thing]
EDIT 3: I took the risk to delete them, but after refreshing the desktop both come back.

Comment: what is in the folders?

Comment: Double click does nothing on them.
How can I know if there's something inside?

Comment: I tried to open them using 7zip too but these doesn't even show up in the C:\users\ady\desktop. I googled and 7zip can view anything, they said.

Answer (score 0):

After I googled both GUIDs I found the answer here:
[2 empty folders still appearing on desktop even after deletion](https://superuser.com/questions/719355/2-empty-folders-still-appearing-on-desktop-even-after-deletion)

This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen folders similar to those names in the root directory of D: disk(not in C:, where your OS is in), the are hidden and usually you can't see it, I deleted them but they will come back after some time. They may be related to programs installed.

Maybe you can safely delete it, but be careful.

Modify the folder option to show hidden  and system protected file may give your more infomation about these files.

Comment: by the way, you may want to find out where these files REALLY are, not just view them in the 'Desktop' view.

Comment: These doesn't have properties in the right click. Also, these weird folders don't show up in file managers or cmd.

Comment: I think using dir /a instead of dir command can give a better result