# Can't delete "Microsoft OneNote Namespace Extension for Windows Desktop Search" from desktop - automatically gets restored

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

After installing [onenote](https://www.onenote.com/) on Win-10 (latest update),  `Microsoft OneNote Namespace Extension for Windows Desktop Search` icon appears on desktop:

[image]

And even after deleting, it automatically restores back over and over again. It doesn't even have properties to hide. Any known solution to permanently remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9qv5ud/wth_is_this_folder_cant_open_it_and_right_click/e8d3u24/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/719355/2-empty-folders-still-appearing-on-desktop-even-after-deletion/986070#986070) websites.

Open Start, type `regedit` and press enter

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`

(Optional: backup the registry tree section. Right-click `Namespace`, click Export, then save the file. If something goes wrong, you can double click that file to restore the registry)

Search for the folder name. Example: **Microsoft OneNote Namespace Extension for Windows Desktop Search**. Fully or partial and make sure that it does matched.

Delete that key (will have a name that looks like `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}`)

The folder should disappear immediately.

Maybe restart once to make sure that it did not come back.